# Rename Refactoring in PyDev broken?

Tags: python, eclipse, rename, pydev, automated-refactoring

I am a bit surprised to find the Rename refactoring facility in PyDev broken.  To see my error

- create a new PyDev project,
- create a new module within it (say `util.py`),

  - create a constant in the module, e. g. `MYCONST = "some const value"`,
- create a second script in the project, say `scriptA.py` which

  - imports `util` and
  - uses the constant: `print util.MYCONST`
- create a third script in the project, say `scriptB.py` which

  - also imports `util` and
  - also uses the constant: `print util.MYCONST`

Renaming of the constant `MYCONST` should rename it in all three files now.

Things like *go-to-declaration* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>left-mouse-click</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>) also work, so the connection between `util.py` and `scriptA.py` is known to PyDev.

But if you rename the constant (using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> on the word `MYCONST`) in the file `scriptA.py`, it gets renamed in `scriptA.py` *and* in `scriptB.py`, but *not* in `util.py` (effectively breaking the code, of course).  If you try renaming it in `util.py`, it gets renamed only within that file and neither in `scriptA.py` nor in `scriptB.py`.

Questions:

1. Can other people recreate my problem?
2. Is there a configuration issue causing the problem so that I can remove the effect myself?
3. Is this a known bug (I didn't find anything concerning it), maybe even with a fix or workaround?
4. Is this only present in my product versions?

I'm using Eclipse "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)" and PyDev 3.9.2.201502050007.

EDIT:

(removed — the bug is not connected to package or not package as it at first appeared to be).

EDIT2:

I just found out that the problem only appears if I import the module name and then use qualified names to access the constant:

```
import util
print util.MYCONST
```

But if I import the name directly:

```
from util import MYCONST
print MYCONST
```

then I cannot reproduce the error.

Though this seems like a workaround (and it might be!), I'd like to be able to use qualified names, at least sometimes.  So the main question remains open.

Comment: You say you have created a module just right after create the project: PyDev  have not complained about no package existing?

Comment: The thing is PyDev don't allow me to create a module outside a package (I'm using the same versions than you, eclipse and pydev).

Comment: So you have imported the files into the project?

Comment: What??  Right-click on the project name in the Package explorer → `New` → `PyDev module` → Choose a `Name` but leave `Package` empty, voila.  That's different for you??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72418/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-alfe).